# What kind of plug adapter should I use when traveling in Indonesia?

Tags: gear, electronic-items, indonesia, power

How would I charge, say, an iPad with the standard U.S. adapter and cable?

(Asked on behalf of [a twitterer](http://twitter.com/#!/texburgher/status/112637173878108160).)

Comment: [Amazon sells](http://www.amazon.com/Power-Adapter-charger-iPhone-Europe/dp/B0043GELNE) a 220V to USB adapter for a $2.48 -- plus 50 cents shipping, so if you feel like splurging on something that can charge your iPad, your iPhone, your Kindle, your camera ...

Comment: buy in Indonesia may get you cheaper cost. It's about 90 cents(USD) or 5000 rupiah if you buy from indonesian shopping malls.

Comment: Should encourage said 'twitterer' to join the site! :D

Comment: The cheating way is to take the USB cable, and just borrow a computer from someone from time to time to charge it with that!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Indonesia uses European-style two-pin round plugs ('C'-type is the most common variant found):

[image]

Voltage is at 220 V 50 Hz (as opposed to 110 V 60 Hz in US). Most modern electronic equipment that has auto-sensing capability should work without needing a voltage converter, you *will* need a plug adapter though which can buy cheap online. As for Apple products specifically have a look at [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/charge-apple-computers-bought-in-usa-to-use-in-europe).

Comment: That's 99% true. However, in Batam and possibly other places, they import everything from Singapore and have the British style electric plug.

Answer (score 2):

What I do when I need confirmation is to check this website:

http://users.telenet.be/worldstandards/electricity.htm

It has an EXHAUSTIVE list of each and every type, the voltage and the countries that use them. It's been handy for some of the stranger countries I've been to and hasn't failed yet.

Myself, I have a multi-adapter. The only country it doesn't seem to handle is South Africa, which has 3 giant prongs - bigger than the UK ones!